# How does timeit works in Python?

Tags: python, timeit

My understanding on "timeit" function is that it returns the time taken for the given snippet of code or function to execute. However when I run for the below, irrespective of the number in range timeit returns almost the same time. why is it so?

```
stmt='''
def countdown():
    for i in range(1000000000000):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n)
        n=n-1
'''

print timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, number=100)
```

Comment: You never actually call the function defined in the statement. So the execution time is just the time to parse it.

Comment: I suppose, if he added enough zeroes to the `range` argument, the parse time could increase. :-)

Comment: How about below? execution time of function or only parsing?
print timeit.timeit('countdown(4)','from __main__ import reccountdown',number=100)

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It's very hard to read—with a whitespace-sensitive language like Python it's virtually impossible. Instead, [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Note that timeit can take a callable as stmt so you can write `timeit.timeit(stmt=countdown, repeat=100)` and you don't have to quote your function definition.